# Using curl to access basic auth protected website via proxy (polipo)

Tags: authentication, proxy, curl, polipo

I am trying to download a file protected via basic auth:

```
curl "http://User:Pass@example.com/blub/bla.bin"
```

This is working fine.

As soon as I tell curl to use my locally installed polipo it fails:

```
$ http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:8123" curl "http://XXXXX:Pass@example.com/blub/bla.bin"
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<title>Proxy error: 504 Host XXXXX lookup failed: Host not found.</title>
</head><body>
<h1>504 Host XXXXX lookup failed: Host not found</h1>
<p>The following error occurred while trying to access <strong>http://XXXXX:Pass@example.com/blub/bla.bin</strong>:<br><br>
<strong>504 Host XXXXX lookup failed: Host not found</strong></p>
<hr>Generated Wed, 12 Mar 2014 22:46:10 CET by Polipo on <em>hostname:8123</em>.
</body></html>
$
```

Is this caused due to an error in Polipo or curl? (Or am I doing it wrong?)

EDIT: `http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:8123" curl -u XXXXX:Pass "http://example.com/blub/bla.bin"` is working fine.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the anwser myself after some more digging:

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html states

> NOTE! According to the URL specification, HTTP URLs can not contain a user
>   and password, so that style will not work when using curl via a proxy, even
>   though curl allows it at other times. When using a proxy, you *must* use
>   the -u style for user and password.

So I was doing it the wrong way :)

Answer (score 11):

Not necessary to use `http_proxy`, try this:

```
curl -x PROXY-SERVER:PORT -U USER:PASS URL
```

`curl -x 127.0.0.1:8123 -U XXXXX:Pass "http://example.com/blub/bla.bin"`